# Toggling the value displayed in a DIV depending on which DIV the click is performed

Tags: javascript, html

I have 4 (or more) DIV elements on which I want to set this behavior:

[image]

1. In the beginning, all DIVs display **A**
2. I click on a random DIV. It must display **B**. Other DIVs must keep displaying **A**
3. If the consecutive click is performed on the same DIV, this later one must display back **A**. Others must keep displaying **A**.
4. If the consecutive click is performed on a different DIV, this later one must display **B**. All other DIVs must display **A**

This is what I am working on. I have had hard time to do anything useful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style>
    .divElt {
        margin-left: 20%;
        width: 80px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
    var data = 'B';
    function funct() {
        var elts = document.getElementsByClassName('divElt')
        for(var i = 0; i < elts.length; i++) {
            elts[i].innerHTML = data
        }
    }
  </script>

  <div class ='divElt' onclick = "funct()"> A
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class ='divElt' onclick = "funct()"> A
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class ='divElt' onclick = "funct()"> A
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class ='divElt' onclick = "funct()"> A
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to resolve this only in JavaScript (no jQuery or other libraries). Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var letterA = "A";
var letterB = 'B';

//Init with all "A"
var elts = document.getElementsByClassName('divElt');
for (var i = 0; i < elts.length; i++) {
  elts[i].innerHTML = letterA;
}


function funct(item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elts.length; i++) {
    if (elts[i] !== item)
      elts[i].innerHTML = letterA;
    else
      elts[i].innerHTML = elts[i].innerHTML === letterA ? letterB : letterA;
  }
}
```

```css
.divElt {
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>

  <script>
  </script>

  <div class='divElt' onclick="funct(this)">
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class='divElt' onclick="funct(this)">
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class='divElt' onclick="funct(this)">
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class='divElt' onclick="funct(this)">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry to disturb you. There is only one very small 'trouble' with your good solution: each time I refresh the page to execute the program for the first time, the first DIV on which I decide to click, must be clicked twice before seeing the data toggled. After that, all DIVs need only once click. May be you know how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you take my code ? If you look closely I have changed the HTML

Comment: Yes, I took exactly your solution. Well, I set an A manually for each DIV so that it does not look blank at the refresh.

Comment: then replace `letterA` by `"A"`

Answer (score 0):

To uniquely identify the div which was clicked, pass `this` to the called function like so `onclick=func(this)`

Then inside your function receive it as a parameter

```
function func(elem) {
    var elts = document.getElementsByClassName('divElt');
    for(var i = 0; i < elts.length; i++) {
        elts[i].innerHTML = 'A';
    }
    elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML === 'B' ? 'A' : 'B';
}
```